# Combining the outputs of multiple SPI devices

Tags: spi, arm, stm32, dsp

I have a project that has an array of digital microphones whose output I would like to perform some fancy signal processing on, using a high-powered ARM micro-processor.

I like the idea of using digital microphones because I don't have to faff around with pre-amps. Anyway, each digital microphone is connected to a dedicated micro-controller that converts the PDM output to PCM.

I need to be able to get each microphone's data onto my ARM micro-processor. Let's assume at this point that everything is synchronized to give the appearance of N-channel concurrent sample and hold ADC. My current thoughts are that each microphone attached micro-controller would buffer its data to some extent and flush it over SPI when its slave select is wiggled by the master. The master would simply talk to each slave in turn.

My question is, is there a more elegant way of implementing this?

This would probably be a perfect job for a FPGA but that's a little beyond my skill level at the moment.

Comment: Are you sure SPI data rate will be sufficient for this job? Anyway, slaves with chipselect inputs will do.

Comment: Excellent question. Some initial tests resulted in getting up to 10MHz. Throughput will be somewhat less of course. Is there a faster communication protocol I could use?

Comment: For multimedia there is something called I2S (not I2C). Never used it or read about it, but perhaps you should :)

Comment: I2S would be a perfect fit.  If you have any questions about it, I use it quite regularly in my own projects so I could help out

Comment: I2S is implemented on a lot of ARM families, e.g. Cortex-M parts like STM32F2/3/4. In their case, it is implemented as an extension of SPI, and usually supports 16, 24 and 32 bit transfers. AFAIK, it's main feature is to move 'proper' audio data, where it is important to synchronise sampling to a very stable clock, to minimise jitter, which is said to be audible at CD-ish sampling rates. To that end, the clock can be a much higher frequency than the actual sample rate. So you may get several x faster than SPI, but would have to use I2S-capable devices at both ends of the transfer.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that although what @gbulmer says is true, it probably only really applies to uC-to-ADC/DAC communication where clocks are closely linked to sample rates. SPI hardware typically employs an arrangement of buffers and shift registers to decouple dependency on the host's clock (in the case of a slave). Therefore uC-to-uC communication is more flexible in this respect when using SPI.

Comment: Well, if the dedicated MCU connected to the mic is capable of the I2S protocol, then I see no reason as to why you couldn't use it uC-to-uC.  Its not a super complicated protocol.  Out of curiosity, what is the main ARM controller you are planning on using?

Comment: STM32F7, it supports I2S as an extension of the SPI protocol :)

Comment: Also consider SPI [independent and daisy-chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus#Independent_slave_configuration) options, depending on the exact timing requirements. For independent and if running out of pins, could use one from the STM as a "slave increment" to another uC behaving as a slave select driver. Again depending on timing needs.

Answer (score 1):

Slaves with chipselect inputs are not a bad idea. This way will cost many ports of your MCU, but if you have this resources, I recommend to stay with this idea.
If you are familiar with RTOS (freertos.org is a free good option) you can implement some code like a SPI driver to share and switch the communication through all slaves. I did this in some of my projects. I called my driver "SPIShared".

By using a RTOS mutex you will protect each slave to do a complete transaction with your master. After that, the mutex is released to allow a new communication.

Observation: you can make a shared SPI even though each has a different slave standard. Before each transaction you will need reinitialize your SPI peripherical with the slave communication standard.